# find if two text boxes in the same row of a table have the same value

Tags: jquery

How can I find if two text boxes in the same row of a table have the same value using JQuery?

Imagine that we have a table with a number of lines and columns and every cells have a textbox inside.

Actually, it is supposed to check duplicate entries for each row of the table once its form is submitted.

Here is the example:

```
<form action="">
    <table class="table" data-month="12">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>column 1</th>
                <th>column 2</th>
                <th>column 3</th>
                <th>column 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <!-- start - row1 -->
            <tr>
                <td class="cell">
                    <input type="text" value="" name="name1">
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <input type="text" value="" name="name2">
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <input type="text" value="" name="name3">
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <input type="text" value="" name="name4">
                </td>
            </tr>                       
            <!-- end - row1 -->

            <!-- start - row2 -->
            <tr>
                <td class="cell">
                    <input type="text" value="" name="name5">
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <input type="text" value="" name="name6">
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <input type="text" value="" name="name7">
                </td>
                <td class="cell">
                    <input type="text" value="" name="name8">
                </td>
            </tr>       
            <!-- end - row2 -->

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you want to target specific row? Depending user interaction? Or check for all? Improve your question please and post any of your own attempt, if any...

Comment: creating and sharing a fiddle would be great

Comment: It is supposed to check each row for duplicate entry once its form is submitted

Comment: @HamidGhorashi Now please, provide your relevant code (HTML and js/jq if any)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
          $('#check').click(function(){
         var idx = {};
        $('.unique').each(function(){
       var val = $(this).val();
      if(val.length)
            {
             if(idx[val]){
                  idx[val]++;
             }
              else{
               idx[val] = 1;   
             }
                }
            });
            var gt_one = $.map(idx,function(e,i){return e>1 ? e: null});
            var isUnique = gt_one.length==0
           alert(isUnique); 
           });
```